# XSL - Replace same name nodes' value with different values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to replace nodes (D) with the same name but in different structures (Body/C and Body/E) according to the match of their values with the values from Rule/Item. Maybe something like a for-each.

I'm using two keys, one with the new values and another with the olds (maybe useless), then I for-each each one but the one with the new values is not giving me anything. Isn't suppose to work?

Another issue, I want to duplicate the parent of the matched node and my XSLT is also doubling the 'Items'.

**Input,**

```
<Message>
<XMLNSC>
    <Translator>
        <Rule>
            <Item>
                <D>RuleD1</D>
                <New>RuleD1</New> <!-- I guess I don't need an element for this -->
                <Original>valD1</Original>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <D>RuleD2</D>
                <New>RuleD2</New> <!-- I guess I don't need an element for this -->
                <Original>valD2</Original>
            </Item>
        </Rule>
        <Body>
            <A>valA</A>
            <B>valB</B>
            <C>
                <D>valD1</D>
            </C>
            <E>
                <D>valD2</D>
            </E>
        </Body>
    </Translator>
</XMLNSC>
```

**Expected**

```
<Message>
<XMLNSC>
    <Translator>
        <Rule>
            <Item>
                <D>RuleD1</D>
                <New>RuleD1</New> <!-- I guess I don't need an element for this -->
                <Original>valD1</Original>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <D>RuleD2</D>
                <New>RuleD2</New> <!-- I guess I don't need an element for this -->
                <Original>valD2</Original>
            </Item>
        </Rule>
        <Body>
            <A>valA</A>
            <B>valB</B>
            <C>
                <D>RuleD1</D>
                <D_Agg>val1</D_Agg>
            </C>
            <C>
                <D>RuleD1</D>
                <D_Agg>val1</D_Agg>
            </C>
            <E>
                <D>RuleD2</D>
                <D_Agg>val2</D_Agg>
            </E>
            <E>
                <D>RuleD2</D>
                <D_Agg>val2</D_Agg>
            </E>
        </Body>
    </Translator>
</XMLNSC>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- copy nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="Translator/Rule//*" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::Translator), '|', name())"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref_new"     match="New" use="text()"/>
    <xsl:key name="ref_origin"  match="Original" use="text()"/>


    <!-- duplicate matched node's parent -->
    <xsl:template match="Translator//*[not(self::Rule)][*[key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::Translator), '|', name()))]]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- replace matched node's value -->
    <xsl:template match="Body//*[key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::Translator), '|', name()))]">

        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fieldValue" select="."/>

        <!-- <xsl:copy> -->
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::Translator), '|', name()))"/> -->
        <!-- </xsl:copy> -->


        <xsl:for-each select="key('ref_new', text())">
            <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="key('ref_origin', text())">
            <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}_Agg">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Altogether as a fiddle:**
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTM/2

Answer (score 0):

Because your XSLT stylesheet is complex and I don't know what's important, I tried to change as little as possible to achieve your desired result.

1. I changed your second `xsl:key` to

   ```
   <xsl:key name="ref_origin"  match="Item" use="Original"/>
   ```

   This makes the `D` child accessible which is used in the last `xsl:for-each`, but preserves the value of your key.
2. I changed your *identity* caller template to avoid doubling the `Item` elements by adding an `xsl:if` around the second call

   ```
   <!-- duplicate matched node's parent -->
   <xsl:template match="Translator//*[not(self::Rule)][*[key('ref', concat(generate-id(ancestor::Translator), '|', name()))]]">
       <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
       <xsl:if test="not(self::Item)">
           <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
3. I added another element to the last `xsl:for-each` to add the `D` element which is accessed from the `xsl:key` mentioned above

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="key('ref_origin', text())">
       <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
           <xsl:value-of select="D"/>       <!-- Using the D child of the Item from the key -->
       </xsl:element>
       <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}_Agg">
           <xsl:value-of select="$fieldValue"/>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

Now the output should be as expected.